# Mocked Eloquent Model returns array instead of Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-7

**Strange problem**: The method `first` of the mocked model returns an *array* instead of the *model*.

See the code below (Laravel + Eloquent + PHPUnit + Mockery).

## Eloquent Model

```
public function getByEmail(string $email) : User
{
    return $this->whereHas('emails', function ($query) use ($email) {
        $query->where('email', $email);
    })->first();
}
```

This works fine. It returns a model of type User.

## Repository

```
public function getByEmail(string $email) : array
{
    return $this->model->getByEmail($email)->toArray();
}
```

Which works fine too :-)

## Test with Mockery

```
/** @test */
public function it_fetches_an_user_by_email()
{
    $email = 'foo@bar.foo';

    $this->userMock
        ->shouldReceive('getByEmail')
        ->once()
        ->with($email)
        ->andReturn(['user' => 'foo']);

    $userRepository = new UserEloquentRepository($this->userMock);
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('user', $userRepository->getByEmail($email));
}
```

**My problem now:**: The method `first` of the mocked model returns an *array* instead of the *model*.

Comment: Maybe I'm being silly – where do you use the getByEmail in the Mockery test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first()` is never being called.

You have this in your test:

```
$this->userMock
    ->shouldReceive('getByEmail')
    ->once()
    ->with($email)
    ->andReturn(['user' => 'foo']);
```

This is telling the mocked user object what to return when `getByEmail` is called; you've told it to return an array (`['user' => 'foo']`). It never actually calls the `getByEmail` method on your `User` model.

### Edit

The method you defined on the `User` model is not called; you are using a mocked object. In your test, when you call `getByEmail()` on your repository, it calls `getByEmail()` on your mocked object. You have told the mocked object to return the array (`['user' => 'foo']`) when `getByEmail()` is called.

You need to tell your mocked object to return the correct data (which is a `User` object, not an array).

Try this:

```
$this->userMock
    ->shouldReceive('getByEmail')
    ->once()
    ->with($email)
    ->andReturn(new \App\User(['user' => 'foo']));
```

Either that, or define return to be another mocked user object that should receive the `toArray()` method and return the array `['user' => 'foo']`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what you mean. I mock the model and call the method getByEmail with param $email. If it works,  it returns a fake array. That's it, right?

Comment: My test passes if I remove toArray() from the repository. That's why I think the mock us correct. But, I expect an Eloquent model from the model inatead of an array.

Comment: @schellingerht If you remove `toArray()` from the repo, your test passes, but only because your mocked object is not returning what it is supposed to. The real object will be returning a `User` object; your mocked object is defined to return an array. Your mocked object is returning the wrong data.

Comment: thanks for your help. See my answer below. If you add this to your answer, I will mark it as the right answer. You're totally right.

Comment: really thanks for your help. I used faker for faking data with a test database. Mocking was unnecessary. Thanks!